# How do I set up all integration tests to use a database that is created on startup

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, integration-testing

I want to have all my integration tests use the same database.  I want to create that database by "Publishing" my database project in source control.

After the selected amount of tests were run, I want to delete that database.

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen successfully being used [hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/) - it's a

> open source in-memory data grid solution.

so you can pretty easy set it up as a [sandbox DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)). It'll live as long as your tests need it. Maybe the most visible advantages are elasticity and scalability.

> I want to create that database by "Publishing" my database project in source control.

Putting it in Git should be straightforward as well - take a database dump, and put it under version control. This way it is just a flat text file. it's good to keep both a data dump, and a schema one. This way using diff it becomes fairly easy to see what changed in the schema from revision to revision.